# Find Postfix to Prefix expression

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, prefix, postfix-notation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Postfix to Infix conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908510/postfix-to-infix-conversation)

What would be the prefix notation of this expression? I can not solve this expression

```
6 a b 7 * + - c d g / + e ^ f * +
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You asked this yesterday and your question was closed. Please do not reask the same questions again, especially such poor questions, not showing a specific problem of yours and not specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Postfix To Infix::**

```
6 a b 7 * + - c d g / + e ^ f * +

6 a (b*7) + - c d g / + e ^ f * +
6 {a  + (b*7)} - c d g / + e ^ f * +
[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]  c d g / + e ^ f * +
[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]  c (d  / g)  + e ^ f * +
[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]  {c + (d  / g)} e ^ f * +
[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]  [{c + (d  / g)}  ^ e]  f * +
[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]  ([{c + (d  / g)}  ^ e]  * f)  +
[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]   + ([{c + (d  / g)}  ^ e]  * f)
```

**Infix To Prefix::**

```
[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]   + ([{c + (d  / g)}  ^ e]  * f) 

[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]   + *[{c + (d  / g)}  ^ e]  f
[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]   + *[{c + (/ d g)}  ^ e]  f
[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]   + *[{+ c / d g}  ^ e]  f
[6  - {a  + (b*7)}]   + (*^+ c / d g e  f)
[6  - {a  + (*b7)}] + (*^+ c / d g e  f)
[6  - {+a  *b7}] + (*^+ c / d g e  f)
[-6  +a  *b7] + (*^+ c / d g e  f)
+[-6  +a  *b7]  (*^+ c / d g e  f)
+-6 +a  *b7  *^+ c / d g e  f
```

Answer (score 1):

The in-order expression will be

```
[6-(a + b*7)] + [(c + d/g) ^ e]*f
```

from that you can find the pre-order, which is
    + -6 + a * b 7 * ^ + c / d g e f

Comment: But what is the procedure. I have find stack operation and using bracket shortcut method. But when using stack operation the result is different -6+a*b7++c/dg^e*f  << Why the result is different?